# Java generics understanding

Tags: java, generics

Could you please explain to me what happens here and why it works without errors.

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(1);
```

I'm sorry, if there already were similar questions, I failed to properly formulate the question so can't google it

Comment: Do you have compiler warnings turned on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here exposes the weakness of type erasure, the mechanism behind Java generics. The implementation of ArrayList does not change when you change its generic type parameter: it's always java.lang.Object behind the scene.

Since you did not give a type parameter to the interface when declaring your list, compiler allows you to add objects of any type, not only Strings. In particular, int gets autoboxed into java.lang.Integer, so the value of 1 can be added to your list.

Comment: So, nothing at all depends on ArrayList type parameter? Only List's parameter matters?

Comment: @MaxVasileusky Correct, since the type gets erased after the compile time, and because the type of the variable does not depend on what you assign it, only the generic parameter of the List interface in the declaration matters.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) `List list` is approximately equivalent to using `List<Object>` without type checking. This type of `List` will accept any type of object. The statement

```
list.add(1);
```

autoboxes an `Integer` to add to the `List`

Comment: That's due to generic invariance, have a look at this [snippet](http://ideone.com/C1AkJ7)

Comment: A List of unknowns (`?`) does not permit any addition (except for `null`)...

Comment: Actually List l is not even equivalent to List <?>. I messed up with the concept. Apology.

Comment: Yes you are right. But it ain't equivalent to writing List<Object> either. :)

Comment: Well it's not _exactly_ equivalent (as no warning is produced) but _is_ functionally equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Generics of the reference is important. So

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

makes no sense. It must be

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you don not provide at generics for the reference type(not the actual object type) it is taken to be as `Object`. So you can add anything to it.

Also generics is a compile time phenomenon. So when you say how it works it means how your code is compiling without compilation errors. It is for a simple reason that no generics associated with the reference Object and hence is taken as Object(default).

Answer (score 1):

```
Could you please explain me what happens here and why it works without errors.
```

[Type erasure.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Java generics exist only at compile time. If you try to shove an `int` into something that is only declared as `List`, (which is bound to `Object`s by default) at runtime, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. if you're familiar with C++, generics are kinda like templates (with few exception, but lets not dig that detail). The main idea of Generics is for type safety in your code and hence clarity. This is great for static typed languages like Java. List is an interface and Arraylist extends from it. Hence its a parent (super class) is List. List has features like sublist, etc.

list.add(1) simply calls the add method of the list interface (which is overridden in Arraylist) to add that element to the array.

Also use:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>
```

great article on generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/